# Create Folder on Homescreen Android

Tags: android

A major part of my app I am creating is to allow the user to create a folder on their homescreen that they can put apps into and customize. I have done some searching around and honestly have no idea if it is possible to do this. I don't see why it wouldn't be able to be done. I have noticed other apps that are avalible for purchase that allow users to do this (for example, edit the icon and name of the folder), what can I do to do that for example? Thanks!

Comment: When I long press my home screen, I have an option named "Folder" under "Add to Home Screen".  I'm running a Galaxy SIII with Verizon with Android Version 4.1.2.

Comment: Ok so do you think there might be any way I could possibly edit that folder? Or maybe make one of my own in the app that can be put onto the homescreen?

Comment: That's what I was saying.  If I follow the directions above, I can make a folder named whatever I want and put whatever apps in it I want.

Comment: Right but I want to add another detail to that where the user can change the background of the folder (i.e. when they open the folder up, they can change the background behind their apps)

Comment: For that level of functionality, I wouldn't know what code to point to.  I looked for source for the "Folder" widget but came up dry.  I'll certainly comment if I find something.

Comment: I just thought of something. What if I could create the actual folder in the app and then make it a drag and drop object that could go onto the home screen. Would that possible work? Thanks for your time by the way :)

Comment: Anything on the Home Screen is a widget, AFAIK.  So you're right back at your original concept of a draggable object on the Home Screen that you have greater options for customization.

Comment: So the folder would end up having to be created on the homescreen? Sorry you lost me. So are you saying that I can have a draggable object in the app that can be dragged into the homescreen or that it has to be created on the homescreen itself as a widget? Also, since it is a widget, how does that provide for greater customization?

Comment: Take a look at this article, it should clarify some things.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I also took a look at [live folders](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/04/live-folders.html) Could I just do this?

Comment: Is there a way I could allow the user to create the live folder in the app and then when they do a long click, it would show that folder for them to chose? Maybe through an OnClick method that somehow lets them do this? Just throwing out some ideas.